# Trouble in resolving dependencies conflict for Firebase subspecs pod

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to fix the versions of my firebase subspec pods in order to keep the Podfile.lock to be constant throughout the team, but there is some error being popped up while installing the pods using `pod install`. I have checked the latest versions of all the subspecs using `pod outdated` command, and then put the desired versions in front of the subspecs.

I have tried running `pod repo update`, but even that didn't work

**Podfile**

```
pod 'Firebase','6.23.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig','4.4.9'
```

**Error Log while running pod install**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod 
"FirebaseAnalytics":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.3.0, ~> 6.0)

In Podfile:
  Firebase/Analytics was resolved to 6.23.0, which depends on
    Firebase/Core (= 6.23.0) was resolved to 6.23.0, which depends on
      FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.4.2)

Specs satisfying the `FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.3.0, ~> 6.0), 
FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.4.2)` dependency were found, but they required 
a higher minimum deployment target.
```

When i run `pod outdated`, I get the following versions of all the subspecs, so accordingly I gave the versions in the Podfile.

```
- Firebase 6.18.0 -> 6.23.0 (latest version 6.23.0)
- FirebaseABTesting 3.1.2 -> 3.2.0 (latest version 3.2.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics 6.3.0 -> 6.4.2 (latest version 6.4.2)
- FirebaseCore 6.6.3 -> 6.6.7 (latest version 6.6.7)
- FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 1.2.1 -> 1.2.4 (latest version 1.2.4)
- FirebaseDynamicLinks 4.0.7 -> 4.0.8 (latest version 4.0.8)
- FirebaseInstallations 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 (latest version 1.2.0)
- FirebaseInstanceID 4.3.2 -> 4.3.4 (latest version 4.3.4)
- FirebaseMessaging 4.3.0 -> 4.3.1 (latest version 4.3.1)
- FirebaseRemoteConfig 4.4.8 -> 4.4.9 (latest version 4.4.9)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't share pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson I will edit the same, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing pods and sub-specs.

Firebase is at version 6.23.0 (see [its podspec](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase.podspec)). This Pod has a sub-spec called "[Firebase/RemoteConfig](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/ec670ae0bb7a37072bdf334d5d2b170e0abc0033/Firebase.podspec#L129)" which pulls in another Pod called `FirebaseRemoteConfig`, which in turn has version [4.4.9](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseRemoteConfig.podspec)

So, your specification of `pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig','4.4.9'` makes no sense, because the sub-spec of a pod does not have its own individual version number. This is what

> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 4.4.9)`.

is trying to tell you.

Use `pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig','4.4.9'` instead.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, now i updated my question with the desired changes, and now a new error is coming, is it related to the min deployment target of the project, should I up the deployment version?

Comment: Definitely sounds like it, yes. What is your current deployment target? Make sure you specify the same version both in your App's Xcode project and in the Podfile.

Comment: well, it is 11.0, and i want to keep the min, deployment target as 11.0 only. and I have checked that both the podfile and the Xcode project have same targets

Comment: does the Podfile specify other platforms besides ios?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the pod as below,

```
pod 'Firebase','6.23.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics','6.23.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging','6.23.0'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks','6.23.0'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig','4.4.9'
```

This worked fine without any issues.